# building openssl for android : unrecognized command line option '-mandroid'

Tags: android, qt, gcc, openssl

I'm trying to build `openssl-1.0.2l` for android in windows base on this toturial : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html

I have the latest mingw/msys and my gcc version is :

```
$gcc --version
gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
```

The problem is when I try the following command

```
make CALC_VERSIONS="SHLIB_COMPAT=; SHLIB_SOVER=" build_libs
```

It gives me this error  :

```
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mandroid'; did you mean '-mrdrnd'?
make[1]: *** [cryptlib.o] Error 1
```

Why gcc does not recognize this flag ?!

Comment: It sounds like you are using the host's GCC (x86?) and not the target's GCC (ARM). You should probably install an ARM cross-compiler.

Comment: OpenSSL has already been ported to Android. If you want to compile it you would need Android NDK.